# Simple RSA code

Tags: python, encryption, rsa

Hi I am trying to create a working RSA program, but on a very small level, I am having problems encrypting and decrypting with this code, can someone help me figure out what is wrong? I have tried doing this many different ways, but this way seems to be the right math, so I believe it might just be my lack of coding skills? Thanks

```
import random, math

def RandomPrime():
  prime = False
  while prime == False:
    n = 2
    while n % 2 == 0:
      n = random.randint(10000, 100000)
    s = math.trunc(n**0.5)
    s = int(s)
    x = 3
    # While n doesn't exactly divide to equal 0, and x is less then the sqrt of n
    while ( n % x != 0 ) and (x <= s):
      x = x + 2
    # if n is greater than s, it means it has run out of numbers to test, so is prime
    if x > s:
      prime = True




  return n

def Modulus(p, q):
    M = p * q
    return M

def Totient(p, q):
    T = ((p-1) * (q-1))
    return T

def Pubkey(T):
  prime = False
  while prime == False:
    n = 2
    while n % 2 == 0:
      n = random.randint(3, T)
    s = math.trunc(n**0.5)
    s = int(s)
    x = 3
    # While 
    while ( n % x != 0 ) and (x <= s):
      x = x + 2
    if x > s:
      prime = True
  return n

def privkey( T, n):
    y = math.fmod(1, T)
    d = float((y / n))
    return d


# z is my encyption in this scenario 
z = 8
# I generate p and q, using my random prime generator, i used low primes in
# this example just to see if it would work but it is still not showing reults
p = RandomPrime()
q = RandomPrime()
print(p, q)
#This creates the modulus
M = Modulus(p, q)
print(M)
# Eulier's totient
T = Totient(p, q)
print(T)
#Pub key creation
n =  Pubkey(T)
print(n)
#Priv key creation
d = privkey(n, T)
print(d)


enc = (pow(z, n)) % M
print('enc: ', enc)


dec = (pow(enc, d)) % M
print('dec: ', dec)
```

Comment: You missed to tell us which programming language you are using. Edit your question and add it at least as a tag.

Comment: its python, sorry mate

Comment: What's your error? And are you able to compute (pow(z, n))? it should be a huge number for an arbitrary n.

Comment: it seemed like it was as the whole program was running, but when I test pow(z, n) separately it does not solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Your `privkey` function appears wrong - I'm guessing you saw the definition of RSA's private key value as something like:

```
the value "e" such that e * d = 1 mod Phi(N)
```

However in this case, `1 mod Phi(N)` does **not** mean `The remainder when 1 is divided by Phi(N)` (which appears to be the way you have translated it into code, based on your use of `math.fmod(1, T)`, but in fact should be read more like:

```
the value "e" such that (e * d) mod Phi(N) = 1
```

This value is generally calculated using the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm). An example Python implementation is [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Mathematics/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).

It's also worth noting that you seem to be defining `privkey(T, n)` but calling it as `privkey(n, T)`.

Comment: How should I rearrange that formula to just get d?

Comment: @user3181295 You'll need to use an algorithm such as the Extended Euclidean Algorithm (linked in the answer above) to perform the calculation.

Comment: The very first Google result for "Extended Euclidean algorithm python" has an example implementation.

Comment: I still struggle to put it into python though, can't you just help me with that?

Comment: It's already *in* python, I don't know how it could be made any easier. If you're still having difficulties, you should post another question.

Comment: But trying to find 'd' the private key is hard for me, just because you find it easy to understand doesn't mean I do, why can't you just help?

Comment: @user3181295 *All* the information necessary to resolve your issue is in the answer or trivially searchable. If you are not capable of literally copying and pasting sample code, then perhaps attempting an implementation of RSA is not a good place to start coding? StackOverflow is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 0):

Check my blog which in detail contains the implementation of the following using python:

MD5 Secure hash Algorithm RFC 1321, RSA public Key cryptography RFC 3447, OpenPGP RFC 4880

```
def keyGen():
    ''' Generate  Keypair '''
    i_p=randint(0,20)
    i_q=randint(0,20)
    # Instead of Asking the user for the prime Number which in case is not feasible,
    # generate two numbers which is much highly secure as it chooses higher primes
    while i_p==i_q:
        continue
    primes=PrimeGen(100)
    p=primes[i_p]
    q=primes[i_q]
    #computing n=p*q as a part of the RSA Algorithm
    n=p*q
    #Computing lamda(n), the Carmichael's totient Function.
    # In this case, the totient function is the LCM(lamda(p),lamda(q))=lamda(p-1,q-1)
    # On the Contrary We can also apply the Euler's totient's Function phi(n)
    #  which sometimes may result larger than expected
    lamda_n=int(lcm(p-1,q-1))
    e=randint(1,lamda_n)
    #checking the Following : whether e and lamda(n) are co-prime
    while math.gcd(e,lamda_n)!=1:
        e=randint(1,lamda_n)
    #Determine the modular Multiplicative Inverse
    d=modinv(e,lamda_n)
    #return the Key Pairs
    # Public Key pair : (e,n), private key pair:(d,n)
    return ((e,n),(d,n))
```

Blog Link :[Python Cryptography](http://crypto-python.blogspot.in/2017/06/pycrypt.html)

Github Link : [Python Cryptography](https://github.com/harsha0795/pyCrypt)